# jquery.min.js Conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I add the below script ,it effecting other functionality of the project(Spring Application)

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

My Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${ctx}/js/easy.notification.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $.noConflict();

    $(function() {
            $("input[type='text']").blur(function() {

                if (this.value === '') {
                    $.easyNotificationEmpty('Warning : You left this field empty !');
                } else {
                    $.easyNotification('Saved Successfully !');
                }
            })
        });
</script>
```

I suspect that it because of the conflict of `jquery-1.3.2.min.js`

I have tried `$.noConflict();`, but am not getting desired results.

Please help me to resolve this problem,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider changing `$.noConflict();` to `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: If you call `$.noConflict()` you can't then go on to call `$()` on the next line... Or are you trying to run another version of jQuery at the same time? What was the original problem that prompted you to try `$.noConflict()` in the first place? Did it produce errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Remove jQuery and easy.notification script tags from your HTML, and do a `console.log($)` - let us know what you get from that and we may be in a better position to answer your question.

Comment: @nnnnnn is right. You'd have to replace all instances of ```$``` with ```jQuery```.

Comment: @Ronak @nnnnnn I am getting same results after changing it to `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Are you sure jquery-1.3.2.min.js is getting included?

Comment: @thefourtheye I also not sure what happened, I think jquery.min.js file was conflicting with the existing jquery.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("input[type='text']").blur(function() {

        if (this.value === '') {
            $.easyNotificationEmpty('Warning : You left this field empty !');
        } else {
            $.easyNotification('Saved Successfully !');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: @thefourtheye: there is no `s` in `noConflict()` http://jsfiddle.net/Hy2h9/2/ and reason for work is, the handler passed to the .ready() method can take an argument, which is passed the global jQuery object. This means we can rename the object within the context of our .ready() handler without affecting other code

Comment: Your code uses `Jquery` instead of `jQuery`. Then how does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Use [$.noConflict();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) before you include new jquery plugin like below,

```
//your old plugin here

<script type="text/javascript">

$.noConflict();

</script>

// new plugin here 

//new script here
```

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing `jQuery.noConflict` on the alias you'll be using on the script that causes other scripts to break.

```
var someAlias = $.noConflict();
```

And use *someAlias* instead of *$* on the script that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could test that and see if this makes any difference:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function() {
            $("input[type='text']").blur(function() {

                if (this.value === '') {
                    $.easyNotificationEmpty('Warning : You left this field empty !');
                } else {
                    $.easyNotification('Saved Successfully !');
                }
            })
        });
})(jQuery.noConflict(true))
```

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6zXXJ/

Answer (score 0):

I use with TRUE,... this work!:

```
//your old plugin here


<script type="text/javascript">

$.noConflict(true);

</script>

// new plugin here
```

Comment: This question is more than 1 year old, it was already answered, and one of it's answers includes your suggestion, thus your answer is no needed. Pay more attention next time, before posting ;)