# how to use jquery noConflict for the given example

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am new to using jquery. I need to use a jquery js file sent by a third party within our codebase. unfortunately it conflicts with the lib already used. I tried to use noConflict code but the functions within js file are not recognizing same. can someone please help me to use noConflict within the js file provided by third party. Below is the example:

```
    <script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="thirdparty.class.js"></script> //this is third party js that uses jquery as well

    <script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var test = new Test({ 
          baseUrl: 'http://example.com', 
          interval: 15000,
          testId: 8,

        });
      });
    </script>

below is the test.class.js sample file

function Test(parameters)
{
  if (parameters == undefined)
  {
    console.log("parameters must be defined");
    return;
  }

  if (parameters.baseUrl == undefined)
  {
    console.log("base url must be defined");
    return;
  }

  //complete code is not posted
}
```

Is there anyway i can avoid using jquery "$" in my code and third party js?

Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var test = new Test({ 
          baseUrl: 'http://example.com', 
          interval: 15000,
          testId: 8,

        });
    });
});
```

and also you can always use `jQuery` instead of `$`

[jquery.min.js Conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086982/jquery-min-js-conflicts/17087132#17087132)

Answer (score 0):

Use the noConflict() method to specify a new name for the jQuery variable:

Example

```
var test=$.noConflict(); 

 test(document).ready(function() {
    var test = new Test({ 
      baseUrl: 'http://example.com', 
      interval: 15000,
      testId: 8,

    });
  });
```

If you have a block of jQuery code which uses the $ shortcut and you do not want to change it all, you can pass the $ sign in as a parameter to the ready method. This allows you to access jQuery using $, inside this function - outside of it, you will have to use "jQuery":

```
 $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($)
  {
   var test = new Test({ 
    baseUrl: 'http://example.com', 
   interval: 15000,
   testId: 8,

    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The test.class.js also uses $ variable for jquery. Does using noConflict in this way also work for third party script?

Comment: Hi. unfortunately this method di not work for the jquery code inside third party script. Any other suggestions?